# Constrain multiple items together in the center of the screen in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

![enter image description here][1]I am currently making a TicTacToe app and I have 9 colored boxes that I would like in the exact center of the screen on any device. I do not have the experience in constraining very well and can't figure out how to do it exactly. I have put a picture to this question to show how it looks in the interface builder. If any one can help me, that would be of great help. (EDIT: DOES NOT LET ME POST PICTURES!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the image sixes are fixed for all devices and orientations then you can simple make a UIView and add these images in the order you want them to be shown and apply basic constraints.

if the image sixes are to grow then make use of spacer views. For the use of spacer view's refer [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutbyExample/AutoLayoutbyExample.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH5-SW1) and applying basic constraints refer these links [link 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2) and [link 2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20897/beginning-auto-layout-part-2-of-2) after that you will be able to  solve all constraint related issues

Comment: Thank you, that was very stupid of me to forget such a simple thing.

Answer (score 1):

create a UIView that contains all boxes. You can center the UIView with a simple constraint in IB and you can arrange the boxes in the view as you like.